# Como chamar o formulário dentro de outro - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tenho o formulário pai com um menuStrip.
Já setei ele como **isMdiContainer = True**

E tenho outro formulário que chamo de Serviços.

No evento Click do menuStrip > Serviço eu coloquei isso:

```
frmCadastroServico CadastroServico = new frmCadastroServico();
CadastroServico.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
CadastroServico.Show();
```

Porém ainda assim ele não abre dentro do principal e sim uma janela nova, como posso resolver isso?

---

Está sendo aberto o formulário filho deste tamanho: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa definir o formulário pai (parent) do seu novo form:

**Exemplo:**

```
frmCadastroServico CadastroServico = new frmCadastroServico();
CadastroServico.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
CadastroServico.MdiParent = this; // < - Adicione isto
CadastroServico.Show()
```

**Para que fique maximizado:**

```
CadastroServico.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
CadastroServico.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
```

**Para esconder os botões maximizar e minimizar:**

```
CadastroServico.MaximizeBox = false;
CadastroServico.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Comment: obrigado mano resolveu.. Tem algo que eu possa fazer pra ele abrir do tamanho da janela (pai)? Sem os botões maximizar minimizar etc

Comment: Pronto, editei com exemplo para chegar nisto

Comment: Olha como ficou, editei a pergunta e coloquei a imagem.. será porque preciso pegar exatamente o tamanho do campo do formulário pai?

Comment: Antes do `CadastroServico.Show()` adicione `CadastroServico.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!