# Forma como os forms são abertos - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Bom dia,

Meu problema é que quando inicio o programa ele fica assim:

Ou seja, o formulário filho nem barra de rolagem tem ai corta as demais opções
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver, maximizo o formulário pai, porém fica com um aspecto visualmente estranho, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia fazer o formulário filho "layout" se enquadrar ao formulário pai? (se é que fui claro no que quis falar)

Eu já fiz outras duas perguntas que deixei os códigos, se caso ajude.

[Como chamar o formulário dentro de outro - Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238931/como-chamar-o-formul%C3%A1rio-dentro-de-outro-visual-studio)

[Conflito ao abrir várias telas no menuStrip - Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239013/conflito-ao-abrir-v%C3%A1rias-telas-no-menustrip-visual-studio)

Comment: Você habilitou o AUTOSCROLL?

Comment: agora para quando max voce pode tenta Anchor, agora não da pra mim te mostra, desculpa mais tarde eu posto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia!

Nas propriedados dos componentes como TextBox etc. você tem a opção ANCHOR que redimensiona os campos de acordo com o form!

[image: Conforme mostrado na imagem]

Comment: Preciso ajustar isso para todos componentes? Label, button, textbox etc?

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era isso mesmo que precisava!!!

Comment: Sim, em todos eles. Estamos ai pra isso!

Answer (score 1):

Tente setar o `AutoScroll` como true no seu form. Talvez isso resolva.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou, para quando o formulário pai está na tela padrão, porém quando eu maximizo, se ver na segunda imagem fica aqueles cantos cinzar "vagos".. como poderia ajustar isso? Ou sei lá

Comment: Ao maximizar o formulário, ele ficará daquela forma mesmo. Não conheço nenhuma forma de ajustar o formulário automaticamente. O correto seria você bloquear a maximização desse formulário. É só setar o `MaximizeBox ` como false.

Comment: Consegui Samuel, fiz pelo jeito que o Vitor ali em cima falou, o "Anchor". Obrigado!!

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu. Flww